# Развертка Jenkins 1.27 на WildFly 23

Tags: linux, tomcat, jenkins, wildfly, jboss

На данный момент на моем сервере (не мной) был настроен jenkins 1.27 на развертке контейнера сервлетов Tomcat 9, на котором реализовано свыше 50 джобов и пайплайнов. Есть необходимость перевести с деплоера Tomcat на альтернативный вариант. На официальной документации jenkins есть раздел Other servlet containers, в котором говорится о возможности развертки на wildfly 26, однако там нет конкретной инструкции, как это можно реализовать. Хотелось бы увидеть подробную инструкцию, как перевести с tomcat на wildfly, либо другие альтернативные варианты, как можно это сделать (даже через собственный war деплоер jetty).

Ссылки источников, про которые я говорил:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/servlet-containers/
https://plugins.jenkins.io/wildfly-deployer/